# MVC Data Annotation Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am looking for a simple data annotation attribute that will call a GET end point in either an MVC Controller or WebAPI Controller. Said end point would return a 200 if validation passed or alternatively a 5xx or 4xx if validation failed.

Idea here is that I can get client side validation by writing the validation in the code behind instead of JS. This would be faster than implementing many custom data attributes and their associated jQuery client side validation as described [here](https://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/2012/01/18/custom-unobtrusive-jquery-validation-with-data-annotations-in-mvc-3/).

So what I am looking for is something along the lines of:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [CallBack(~/MyCallBack/PropCheck)]
    public string MyProp {get; set;}
}
```

I realise this is slightly "out there" and that doing it this way is not pure etc. I was hoping someone had seen something that did this. This way adding new validation's with unobtrusive client side validation would be snap as the JS would only have to be written ONCE for the attribute.

All pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: What sort of validation do you want to perform for `MyProp`? MVC comes with the `[Remote]` attribute which makes a call to a controller method to perform validation

Comment: Great answer @StephenMuecke , a simple help link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808(v=vs.98).aspx

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.